# Do we want accepted answers on our site to be unpinned from the top?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Currently, accepted answers are always pinned at the top of the list of answers, regardless whether you sort them by "Active", "Oldest" or "Votes".[1]
Last week, Stack Overflow [stopped pinning accepted answers to the top of the list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/6002174). This has also been announced on Meta SE: [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/340816). This change has not been rolled out to the entire network. In the above Meta SE post, SO employee Nicolas Chabanovsky asks,

> Would you like to have the accepted answer unpinned on your site?

Do you think this change would make sense on French Language Stack Exchange? The advantage of this change is that the sorting of the answers will be based on what the community thinks is the best answer rather than the question owner. We should also bear in mind that on Stack Overflow before the change, any answers, including accepted ones, could become outdated due to technological developments, so an outdated accepted answer would remain pinned at the top even after more up-to-date answers had been added and received more votes. On French Language SE, by contrast, answers are much less likely to become outdated by technological developments, so unpinning the accepted answer seems less urgent here.

[1] If you want to look for examples, here is a [list of question with at least two answers, one of which has been accepted](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=+answers%3A2..+hasaccepted%3Atrue). The query is easy to adapt to filter questions with a higher number of answers.

---

**Update 14.09.2021**: [Meta SE want to collect feedback by 19 September](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/340816). I will base my feedback on the answer that has the highest number of votes.

---

**Update 19.09.2021**: I have posted [feedback from our site to Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370012/340816), so I have removed the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) from this question.

Answer (score 7):

To my mind it would make a lot of sense on French Language for the accepted answers to be unpinned from the top. Obviously not because they would become outdated, but because on some instances the accepted answer is not the one the community finds best. It would also prevent having accepted answers that are wrong being highlighted, as it sometimes happens.

---

À mon avis ce serait logique de ne pas épingler les réponses acceptées sur *French Language* aussi. Évidemment pas parce qu'elles seraient dépassées par un quelconque progrès technologique, mais parce que parfois la réponse acceptée n'est pas celle que la communauté a reconnue être la meilleure. Et ça éviterait aussi que des réponses acceptées bien que carrément fausses ne soient mises en avant, comme cela arrive parfois.

Answer (score 3):

Le fait qu'une réponse soit acceptée signifie qu'elle est la meilleure pour la personne qui pose la question au moment de la sélection. Or ce choix ne fait pas autorité et les critères de sélection peuvent être subjectifs ou dictés par le contenu disponible à ce moment-là. Si on considère que certains utilisateurs fréquentent peu ou une seule fois le site, et qu'ils ne réévaluent pas leurs sélections, et qu'on affirme que le contenu doit servir ceux qui suivront par la suite, il est difficile de comprendre pourquoi on accorderait une grande importance à la sélection en soi, alors encore moins à sa primauté dans l'ordre de présentation. Avec certaines questions on peut avoir plus d'une bonne réponse, soit que l'approche diffère soit que la réponse diffère comme telle etc. On a certainement aucune garantie que la réponse sélectionnée soit complète et la meilleure objectivement. En plus parfois la sélection se fait rapidement.

Par ailleurs le fait qu'une réponse obtienne plus de votes ne signifie pas non plus qu'elle soit la meilleure ou la bonne objectivement et aucune stratégie abusive de vote ne pourrait déloger la position de la sélection si on lui accordait la priorité. Mais à tout le moins celle qui a reçu le plus de votes fait certainement davantage consensus qu'une réponse sélectionnée qui a obtenu moins de votes. On veut valoriser la communauté et croire qu'un plus grand échantillon de votes permet aux réponses les meilleures à ses yeux, et peut-être même objectivement, incluant les contributions qui arrivent après la sélection, de prendre les devants avec le temps. On voit mal pourquoi un choix personnel et potentiellement limité serait exclu de l'impact continuel et contemporain du vote. Il y a certainement moins de risque d'erreur (de présentation pour ainsi dire), dans l'hypothèse où l'ordre de présentation des contenus est significatif et excluant le cas des personnes qui vont systématiquement lire toutes les réponses. D'autre part on sait que la première réponse visible peut donner le ton ou avoir un impact, qu'on a documenté ailleurs, et si c'est le cas on préfère que la communauté, plutôt que la personne qui pose la question, en soit responsable.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the main issue with accepted answers is that the question owner my accept an answer prematurely. This is especially the case with new and inexperience Stack Exchange users and not so much with regular users who have gather a few hundred reputation points.

For this reason, I think the appropriate way of dealing with the accepted-answer feature is not unpinning it [1] but **turning the ability to accept an answer into a privilege** that you earn once you have gained enough reputation. For example, users may acquire this privilege when they have gather **125 reps**, the same level that is required for the [**downvote privilege**](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). (This change need not affect existing accepted answers, since that would require recalculating each user's reps at the time when they accepted an answer.)

[1] The argument that answers get outdated over time due to technological progress is valid on Stack Overflow but hardly relevant on language sites such as French Language SE.

Comment: I'm afraid that preventing new users from accepting answers would be frustrating for them. To avoid premature accepts, it might be simpler to impose a delay (a couple of days maybe) before a response can be accepted by these users (or by any user for that matter). That would let other answers to be suggested, and votes to possibly sort them out.

Comment: We have enough unanswered questions as it is IMHO. I think we also want to encourage people to answer questions, and by removing the 15 reputation incentive coming from an accepted answer, it does not incitate people to do so.